# Does C# allow only one Stack per Thread?

Tags: c#, .net

**Does C# language  allow only one stack per thread?** 
If yes then why so?

Comment: Cause there is no need of more than one stack per thread

Comment: Why are you asking? What do you imagine a second (or more than second) stack might be used for. You can, for example, create a stack as a collection (i.e., a last-in, first-out structure), but it's not a processing stack (that keeps track of execution pointers and local variables)

Comment: Most mentions of stack in the C# language spec are an example class implementing a stack data structure. The exception is for `stackalloc`, although there may be a few more mentions for some of the exotics (Span and ref structs) that have recently been introduced.

Comment: The C# language spec makes no such demands.  This feature in fact exists, first provided by CLR v2.0.  Requires a custom host, IHostTaskManager is the core interface.  Unhappily co-inciding with the multi-core revolution of the 2000s, the Microsoft group that requested it got cold feet and decided not to use it after all.  I don't know of anybody that did not also agree it was a bad idea.

Comment: was going through https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/01/16/what-is-the-defining-characteristic-of-a-local-variable/ by Eric Lippert . It says its not necessary to have one stack per thread and I got confused

Comment: @AbhayKumar - In principle there can be multiple stacks. In practice you're unlikely to encounter such a situation. Eric Lippert mentions it in passing because there are so many misconceptions about "the stack" and it's given *undue* prominence by some people. You can happily ignore its/there existence most of the time and be productive.

Comment: See his [Truth about value types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/) post for another where he's trying to make people *stop* focussing on the stack.

Comment: To extend the Lippert-citing, [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) is also worth reading when talking about the stack in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Yes each C# Thread has its own stack, stacks stores the returning addresses for functions aswell as that function's local variables/arguments.

but if you mean why it only has one stack, then in my experience, you shouldn't need more than one stack per thread, or else you're doing something wrong, it's not meant to be your primary storage per se, anything that will eat up your stack should usually go on the heap, also no one genuinely needs that much recursion either, if you hit that limit, there is usually a better approach out there.